# lisp (prime number) code not working

Tags: lisp, primes

this is a code that takes an input and prints if it is prime or not
the last if always prints "false" , why ?

```
(print "Enter a positive integer")
(setq num (read))
(setq i 2)
(setq prime t)
(loop

(if(=(rem num i)0)(setq prime nil) break)
(incf i) 
(when (<=  (/ num 2)i)(return t))

)

(if()(print "True")(print "False"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Common Lisp the false value, the empty list and the symbol `nil` is the same. Disregarding every line of code except the last is basically:

```
(if nil             ; nil is false
    (print "True")
    (print "False"))
```

So here false is always false so it will always pick the alternative `(print "False")`. That is why.

Other errors:

1. In this code is `setq` variables `i` and `prime` without defineing them and since they will be special they should have been given `*earmuffs*` so that you see they are in contrast to lexical bindings.
2. The `loop` macro is slightly odd in the way it does not use any `loop` macro keywords. There is a evaluation of the variable `break` that seem to be undefined. The `loop` macro is a whole different syntax and language by itself that you need to learn in the same manner as lisp. It is not lispy in it's syntax.
3. You should abstract. Make functions that do some work good. Use them in you code. Here is what I gathered you wanted to do:

```lisp
(defun primep (num)
  (loop :for i :from 2 :to (/ num 2)
        :never (zerop (rem num i))))
```

Comment: when i place prime in the if condition it  says undefined function prime, also what exactly are earmuffs?

Comment: @ahmedmohamed Sound like you are doing `(if (prime) ...)` which calls the function called `prime` and investigates the result rather than `(if prime ..)` which investigates the variable `prime` for truthness. The most common mistake for beginners is adding extra parentheses which change the codes meaning.

Comment: @ahmedmohamed earmuffs refer to the variables that start and end with `*`. like the variable `*test*`. It's a common naming convention to avoid mixing lexical and dynamic variables. In CL global special variables are dynamic and not lexical so if you mistake have made a global scope all other functions using the same variable might start misbehave and it is a bug you'll have a hard time finding. Just using a variable without declaring it is often interpreted as if the variable is dynamic and it poisons all other places you might have used the same variable name.